# Alternative to Angular transclude fallback content in older versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

[`Transclude fallback content`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) is one of the features added to Angular V1.5.0
I'm writing a [dateTimePicker module](https://github.com/AmirkabirDataMiners/ADM-dateTimePicker) for Angular and want to add custom user input template feature for next version and `Transclude fallback content` is exactly what i want, because if user put nothing inside the directive, default template will inject.
But i can't force everyone to use Angular V1.5.X
Is there any alternative solution?

**Another Solution:**
As i have a huge html template and can't make it single line string or ... to put it in JS file, i forked `Mario Lamacchia` idea.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> 
    <div ng-if="defaultTemplate">...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (!element.find('ng-transclude').children().length) {
        scope.defaultTemplate = true;
        element.find('ng-transclude').remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this link function in 1.3.x version gives the same result of the 1.5.x example for transclude fallback content

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  if (!element.find('ng-transclude').children().length) {
    element.find('button').append('<b style="color: red">Button1</b>');
  }
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7VHLsv